# How does one generate a formula(s) for an artificial satellite's location at time $t$ given a set of known locations at discrete times?

Tags: coordinate-systems, orbital-motion, astronomy, satellites

Given a set of spatio-temporal points in space {(Lat_1, Lon_1, Alt_1, Time_1), ... (Lat_n, Lon_n, Alt_n, Time_n)}, I need a function (i.e. a formula) that takes these points (or subset of points) as input and outputs something like (Lat(t), Lon(t), Alt(t)). I.e.:

f(S; t) = (Lat(t), Lon(t), Alt(t)) where S = {(Lat_1, Lon_1, Alt_1, Time_1), ... (Lat_n, Lon_n, Alt_n, Time_n)} or a subset of this set, and t is a time period before, after or in between Time_1 and Time_n.

The purpose of this is to be able to calculate (or at least estimate) where artificial satellites (LEO, MEO, and HEO) are at specific points in time given a set of discrete observations. We can assume there will be more than 3 observations. I'm not sure if the equations for HEOs is more complex due to their shape. If this is a rookie question I apologize as this is admittingly outside of my domain. I am building a python program for this, which is why a function/formula would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In Earth orbit, perturbations of the basic Keplerian trajectories are pretty serious, so one usually employs rather complicated numerical models, like the venerable [SGP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models). I understand that there is an implementation of SGP4 in Python.

When I did this for the HETE-2 mission (in C, not Python), I wrapped a nonlinear fitting function from the GNU Scientific Library around a public domain SGP4 code and fitted the parameters to observations of velocity and position. Sounds easy, but it took some numerical analysis experience to transform the SGP4 parameters to something that didn't get the code trapped by singularities. For a couple of days' work, I saved the project $100,000: that's what the launch contractor wanted to charge for reducing the tracking data.